# How to sort extension in the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

The Google Chrome Web Store seems like a disaster to me. I cannot make sense of it.

How can you sort extensions by popularity? By rating? By amount of downloads? By newest? By recently updated?

Am I completely overlooking something?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions

Comment: You have feature to sort by rating but not by others

Comment: How does the sort by rating work? I sort by 'Developer Tools' and on the first page I see "Capture webpage screenshot" with 12148 reviews which is about ten spots behind "CSS shapes editor" with 66. How does that even work? If I give an extension with a zero reviews a five star rating it gets bumped to the number one spot?

Comment: I know its a little skewed but it has been like that for some time now. See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/29z738/what_happened_to_the_sort_options_for_chrome_web/)

Comment: Last week the Firefox team was doing an AMA on reddit. I should have mentioned they have a serious leg up up

Comment: @winchendonsprings that leg up could actually help with Chrome/Edge extensions as well - search in the Firefox add-on store, and then look for the equivalent in the Chrome/Edge store (statistically the relations in terms of popularity/downloads/newest should be similar): https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/

Answer (score 2):

I have created a simple sorter js which works on Chrome Dev tools console. You can reach the GitHub page [here](https://github.com/ugur1yildiz/ChromeWebStoreSorter).

It mainly sorts the extensions on the Chrome Web Store. It runs on Chrome Dev Tools console which is started by Ctrl+Shift+I.

After opening the search extensions page on the link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/PHRASE?_category=extensions with your search phrase replaced by PHRASE. And than the code under sorter.js is run on the chrome dev cosole.

It firstly loads all the extensions on the infinitly-scroll page by automatically scroll the page until not scroll. Then it sorts them by number of votes.

```js
var i = 0;
var num_of_items = 0;
var stop = false;
function startCheck(max)
{
    i++;
    
    //document.querySelectorAll('div.h-a-Kd.a-Hd-mb')[0];
    var bottom = document.querySelectorAll('div.h-a-Hd-mb.a-Hd-mb')[0];
    bottom.scrollIntoView();
    //scrollTo(scrollX,scrollY+1000); 
    console.log(i.toString());  
    
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('.a-d-na.a-d.webstore-test-wall-tile.a-d-zc.Xd.dd');
    var new_num_of_items = items.length;
    if (num_of_items != new_num_of_items)
    {
        num_of_items = new_num_of_items;
        console.log('Loaded items : ' + new_num_of_items);
    }   
    
    if (i>max || stop) 
    {
        i = 0;
        num_of_items = 0;
        stop = false;
        items[new_num_of_items-1].scrollIntoView(false);
        sortsort();
        return;
    }
    
    var t = setTimeout(function (){startCheck(max);}, 100);
}

var MAX_COUNT = 25;
var counter = 0;
function stopCheck()
{   
    var spin = document.querySelectorAll('div.h-a-Kd.a-Hd-mb')[0];  
    var state_new = spin.attributes.style.value == "display: none;"
    
    if (state_new)
        counter++;
    else
        counter=0;
    
    console.log('Counter : ' + counter);
    if (counter > MAX_COUNT)
    {
        counter = 0;
        stop = true;        
        return;
    }
    
    var t = setTimeout(function (){stopCheck();}, 100);
}

var sortsort = function() {

    var ab = document.querySelectorAll('.a-d-na.a-d.webstore-test-wall-tile.a-d-zc.Xd.dd');
    console.log(ab.length);
    var ab_arry = Array.from(ab);

    var index_str;
    var star_str;
    ab_arry.forEach((star) => {
        
        index_str = star.attributes.hasOwnProperty("index") ? Number(star.attributes.index.value.toString().replace(/,/g, '')) : 0
        star_str  = star.getElementsByClassName("nAtiRe").length > 0 ? Number(star.getElementsByClassName("nAtiRe")[0].textContent.toString().replace(/,/g, '')).toString() : "Not voted";

        console.log( index_str + " = >>>> " + star_str);        
    });

    ab_arry.sort(function (a,b) {
        var a_star =  a.getElementsByClassName("nAtiRe").length > 0 ? Number(a.getElementsByClassName("nAtiRe")[0].textContent.toString().replace(/,/g, '')) : 0;
        var b_star =  b.getElementsByClassName("nAtiRe").length > 0 ? Number(b.getElementsByClassName("nAtiRe")[0].textContent.toString().replace(/,/g, '')) : 0;
        
        return (b_star - a_star);   
    });


    let row_nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.h-a-x > [role="grid"] > [role="row"]');
    var row_nodes_arry = Array.from(row_nodes);
    var sr;

    for (var rr = 0; rr < row_nodes_arry.length; rr++)
    {   
        sr_start = rr * 3;
        
        var msg = rr.toString() + ' <--- ';
        for (var sr = sr_start; sr < sr_start + 3 && sr < ab_arry.length ; sr++)
        {
            msg += '1:' + sr + ' ';
            row_nodes_arry[rr].appendChild(ab_arry[sr]);
        }   
        console.log(msg);
    }

}

startCheck(3000);
stopCheck();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is not possible (nor has it ever been, that I can recall) to do any of these things with the chrome web store "out of the box". Mind if I fork it and make a grease/violentmonkey script?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to do, but here's the little things that you can do:

- **By rating <sup>(1)</sup>:**

  - You can filter by the rating - set the low limit of starts for your results.
- **By recently updated <sup>(2)</sup>:**

  - Recently updated as stated by Google, we can't know if there's more behind it. I guess (from what I see), that's actually "recently updated popular extensions".
- **Popularity <sup>(3)</sup>:**

  - I think the closest would be the **Editor's Picks** section. Those are usually good and popular apps/extensions, and the fact that they're being picked also boosts them.
- **Newest:**

  - Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible. Maybe if there's a feed of updates from the Web Store you can get this information from there.
- **Downloads:**

  - Not really an option, though I think it can be known (more or less) by the other parameters (rating, featured, editor's picks etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to sort extensions by 'recently updated' in a slightly roundabout way by using Google:

For example, I was looking for recent jQuery addons:

- go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), search for...
  '**site:chrome.google.com "jquery"**' (or you could also use '**intitle:"jquery"**')
- click on '**Tools > Anytime**', change it to '**Past week**' or whatever timeframe you want

the results will include both recently added and updated addons

Answer (score 0):

this works for me (**march 2024**)

to press "Load more" button several times

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        document.querySelector('button.Vs7jVd').click();
        await sleep(i * 1000);
    }
    console.log('Done');
}

demo();
```

to sort extensions by ratings

```js
// Function to sort extensions by downloads
function sortExtensionsByDownloads() {
  var extensions = [];
  // Selecting each extension item
  var extensionElements = document.querySelectorAll('[jsname="hs2VQd"]:not(.load-more-button)');
  extensionElements.forEach(function(extension) {
    var name = extension.querySelector('.GzKZcb').innerText.trim();
    var downloadsText = extension.querySelector('.Y30PE').innerText.trim();
    extensions.push({ name: name, downloadsText: downloadsText, element: extension });
  });

  // Sorting extensions by number of downloads
  extensions.sort(function(a, b) {
    return compareDownloads(a.downloadsText, b.downloadsText);
  });

  // Reordering extensions on the webpage
  var parentElement = extensionElements[0].parentNode;
  extensions.forEach(function(extension) {
    parentElement.appendChild(extension.element);
  });
}

// Function to compare download counts
function compareDownloads(a, b) {
  // Regular expression to extract numeric value and unit
  var regex = /([\d.]+)\s*([KM]*)/;
  var matchA = regex.exec(a);
  var matchB = regex.exec(b);

  // Extract numeric value and unit
  var aValue = parseFloat(matchA[1]);
  var aUnit = matchA[2];
  var bValue = parseFloat(matchB[1]);
  var bUnit = matchB[2];

  // Convert units to numerical values
  if (aUnit === 'K') aValue *= 1000;
  if (bUnit === 'K') bValue *= 1000;
  if (aUnit === 'M') aValue *= 1000000;
  if (bUnit === 'M') bValue *= 1000000;

  // Compare numerical values
  return bValue - aValue;
}

// Call the function to sort extensions by downloads
sortExtensionsByDownloads();
```